# sensorLandscape raising a Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to set the correct landscape mode for the different API levels and I encountered a problem:

I've set in the manifest file the orientation of my activity to Landscape, and in the activity code evaluate if the API level is greater and setting it to sensorLandscape if it's greater than API 8, like so:

```
public static final int ANDROID_BUILD_GINGERBREAD = 9;
public static final int SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE = 6;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= ANDROID_BUILD_GINGERBREAD) {
        setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.results);
}
```

It's working great on ICS, JB and GB, but on Honeycomb tablets it crashes on`setContentView`when on portrait mode. On landscape is fine... :S

The layout files are:

```
layout:
    main.xml
layout-land:
    main.xml
    results.xml
```

I don't understand why is not working on HC tablets if the API level should be supporting`sensorLandscape.`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Would you post the complete stack trace, just for curiosity's sake?

Comment: I've set the orientation in the manifest to just plain landscape, commented that if and it's still not working. Here is the stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/Da0xXq0m